# Steam Open ID login image

Tags: openid, steam, branding

I was looking at https://steamcommunity.com/dev and i noticed for the OpenID they say

> If you are using OpenID on your site, we request that you use one of the following buttons as your link to the Steam sign in page.

And then they include two images showing steam logins. My question is, am i forced to use these images? Or can i make my own styled buttons but show the same information? like still include the `Sign in through Steam` and `This site is not associated with Valve Corp.`

Answer (score 0):

Valve says they request you to use these images, but they do not actively enfore it. I've seen many sites that are using custom sign in buttons (bolt.gg for example) and they are still up an running.

If I were you I would still use the provided images just to be on the safe side. But you can probably use custom ones aswell, just include the same text that is on the provided images.